Single sign-on with Rundeck Community
I have read through posts which are a couple years old that has information about implementing SSO for Rundeck community version with a pre-auth mode.
Is there a working example of this? or any new method that has surfaced recently?
Thanks in advance.

Short answer: no new methods right now.
About the examples: You can put a service in front of a web server that passes the headers to Rundeck via pre-auth config. Similar to this or this.
